# How to correctly implement while logic

Tags: c#

I am writing a method to take user input for a menu with three options: 1,2,3. My do while loop runs, however my while logic is still accepting unwanted input. Why is my code not looping for inputs outside of my set range of values?

I have tried different logical operators, removing logical operators and setting while Option < Value.

```
private static MenuOption ReadUserOption()
{
    int Option;
    Console.WriteLine("Please make a selection");
    Console.WriteLine("1, will run TestName, 2 will run Guess that number, 3 Wil quit the program.");
    do 
    {
        Option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return (MenuOption)(Option - 1);
    } while (Option < 1 || Option > 3);

}
```

My goal is for any user input outside of <1 and >3 for the loop to continue until a value within that range is entered. In its current state if I enter 0 the loop will accept that value and output -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move the return statement outside the loop

```
private static MenuOption ReadUserOption()
{
    int Option;
    Console.WriteLine("Please make a selection");
    Console.WriteLine("1, will run TestName, 2 will run Guess that number, 3 Wil quit the program.");
    do 
    {
        Option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    } while (Option < 1 || Option > 3);
    return (MenuOption)(Option - 1);

}
```